# angular2 in visulal studio 2015 typescript project

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015

I have set up an anjular2 demo project in vs2015.  But it seems systemjs is not seeing my compiled js files.

```
System.import('app/boot.js')
    .then(null, console.error.bind(console)); -- WORKS

System.import('app/boot')
    .then(null, console.error.bind(console)); -- DOESN'T
```

Can someone please help?

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            defaultJSExtensions: true
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

my vs2015 project settings

```
<TypeScriptRemoveComments>false</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
<TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap><TypeScriptModuleKind>CommonJS</TypeScriptModuleKind>
<TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>true</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
<TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>true</TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>
<TypeScriptAdditionalFlags> $(TypeScriptAdditionalFlags) --experimentalDecorators </TypeScriptAdditionalFlags>
<TypeScriptAdditionalFlags> $(TypeScriptAdditionalFlags) --emitDecoratorMetadata </TypeScriptAdditionalFlags>
<TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
<TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
<TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
<TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny><TypeScriptOutFile />
<TypeScriptOutDir />
<TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
<TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
<TypeScriptMapRoot />
<TypeScriptSourceRoot />
```

Typescript compiler 1.7.6

the error I am getting in the browser is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined(anonymous function) @
>   boot.ts:1 angular2-polyfills.js:143 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'split' of undefinedreadMemberExpression @
>   system.src.js:1456(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3224(anonymous
>   function) @ system.src.js:3749complete @ system.src.js:2487run @
>   angular2-polyfills.js:138zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111

Comment: whats the error you got  when you using the code without extension i.r without .js ? and secondly have you write `System.config({
                    defaultJSExtensions: true,});` in your index.html file ?

Comment: I updated my post with more detail, hope it helps

Comment: according to error you mentioned the error is your project has not import require.js properly

Comment: the error is coming from browser console, my project in visual studio compiles fine